# Solving $xe^{-x}+2e^{-x}=0$

Tags: logarithms, problem-solving

While I was studying my maths book, I came across this equation:

$$
xe^{-x}+2e^{-x}=0
$$

I tried to solve it in different ways, but each time I break up some rule. My best try was this:

Let's $u=e^{-x}$, thus we have:
$$
xu+2u=0
$$
By taking $u$ as a common factor we get:

$$
u(x+2)=0
$$

By dividing both side by $(x+2)$ we get:

$$
u=0
$$

But $u=e^{-x}$, then:

$$
e^{-x}=0 \\
ln(e^{-x}) = ln(0) ??
$$

$ln(0)$ is obviously wrong, where did I slip?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you divide by $x+2$ how do you know $x+2\neq 0$? Indeed you don't! 
Thats why you should get $u=0$ **or** $x+2=0$. The first equation has no solutions as $u=e^{-x}>0$. The second gives $x=-2$.

You write $e^{-x}=0$. This equation has no solutions. But you can't write $\ln (e^{-x})=\ln (0)$!!!! This is because $\ln (0)$ is not defined!

Comment: @Sp. Note that as above never,never make some exponential terms like $e^a$ equal to $0$. It is absolutely wrong. No additional notes needed for your problem +1 :-)

Comment: $\ln(0!!!!)$ is defined; it's zero. :-)

Comment: @HenningMakholm I believe you know I meant $\ln(0)$ and not $\ln(0!!!)$!

Answer (score 10):

If $xe^{-x}+2e^{-x}=0$, then divide across by $e^{-x}$ (which is non-zero) to get $x+2=0$, which has the solution $x=-2$.

Answer (score 2):

$a\cdot b=0\implies a=0\text{ or }b=0$ so $u=0\text{ or }x+2=0$.

You deduced $u\neq0$ hence $x+2=0$. That is $x=-2$